# Customers cannot connect to Facebook through our app after the app was switched to “Facebook Login for Business”

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Our company transfers Facebook and Instagram data to clients (using Meta Develop account and app). On 26 July 2023 we received a notification that our app was automatically switched over to the new “Facebook Login for Business”. Since then our customers can’t connect to Facebook through our app.
If it’s not possible to use “Facebook Login” for our purposes, how can we switch back to “Facebook Login for Business”? developers.facebook.com doesn’t have any information about it.

Following the instructions on developers.facebook.com, our app was switched to “Facebook Login”, but it still doesn’t work.
Therefore I have a few questions:

```
1. Can we somehow use “Facebook Login” to transfer data to our customers as before?  What changes (in account settings or in code) do we need to make?
2.
```

Comment: 2. If it’s not possible to use “Facebook Login” for our purposes, how can we switch back to “Facebook Login for Business”? developers.facebook.com doesn’t have any information about it.

Comment: Did you have an update on this Stefan?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a new App as a Business type to use the “Facebook Login for Business” product.